# How do i call a FormView in a ChildForm in MFC C++ MDI Application

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi, mdichild

As the tittle says

How i can call a FormView to a ChildForm? in MDI App?

I have seen a lot of answer for C# and others languages but i'm programming with MFC C++ and nobody has answered this question yet(only about MainFrame for SDI)

Basically this is the body of question:

- How i can apply my FormView into a ChildFrame(CMDIChildWnd)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`CFormView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/353dcby6.aspx) is derived from [`CScrollView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t073d82.aspx), I don't see a problem here, if your replace the `CView` of the MDI with `CFormView`.

One uncomely thing is of course the fixed size of the controls in the variable frame, which is not an overly elegant design and makes `CFormView` a bit dated in my opinion. MFC is a rather old architecture and thus a variable handling of dialog controls is nothing you get out of the box, but in past projects, I found [ResizableLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1175/ResizableLib) handy to overcome the fixed layout. There is a `CResizableMDIChild` class you can use. This is still not as elegant and easy to use as in WPF or Windows Forms, but it works.